# Enable rich text formatting and keep formatting

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am developing a new Excel document that we will use to input information, then use that information to generate an email from an OFT template. Basically, the VBA looks for a certain string within the OFT, then replaces that with the contents of a cell or activex textbox. For example:

Cell reference:

```
.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "&lt;&lt; summary &gt;&gt;", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H3"))
```

ActiveX Textbox reference:

```
.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "&lt;&lt; previous-updates &gt;&gt;", ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("PreviousUpdates").Object.Text)
```

The problem I'm having is formatting the text within the "PreviousUpdates" textbox. I can format the text within it in HTML, and it imports in to the OFT template correctly. However, many of my colleagues don't know HTML, so won't be able to format the text that way. With that in mind, my question is two fold:

1. How can I enable rich text formatting within the "PreviousUpdates" textbox?
2. How can I ensure that this formatting is maintained when it is "exported" to the OFT template?

TIA for any help.

Comment: Just a thought, can you not copy the text from you textbox into a cell, format the text and then use that in your replace? that way you don't need 2 different statements for replace as well.. just a thought

Comment: Hmmm I never thought of that. It could be a possibility, but the idea is to make it easy to populate for users so it looks the same in the XLS as it does in the email.

I'll certainly give that a try as a short-term workaround though. Thanks.

Comment: I would have it in a hidden cell that way users would be non the wiser or you could just copy it in cell `H3` as that's the one users presumably populate in the sheet

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I haven't found a fix to my initial question, I have managed to come up with a workaround based on the feedback Zac provided. I kinda took his idea and ran with it. Thought I would post up my workaround in case anyone is having the same issue.

So, what I did was use a Replace statement to format the text in HTML, populate the HTML email template, then remove the HTML tags so that the text is still formatted correctly in Excel. Here is an example of my code:

```
    ' Add HTML formatting to text updates so it displays correctly in the email.
PreviousUpdates.Text = Replace(PreviousUpdates, vbCrLf, "<br>")
LatestUpdate.Text = Replace(LatestUpdate, "-", "<li>")
LatestUpdate.Text = Replace(LatestUpdate, vbCrLf, "<br>")

' Populate the HTML email template.
.Subject = Replace(.Subject, "<< REF >>", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C3"))
.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "&lt;&lt; summary &gt;&gt;", Summary.Text)
.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "&lt;&lt; latest-update &gt;&gt;", LatestUpdate.Text)
.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "&lt;&lt; previous-updates &gt;&gt;", PreviousUpdates.Text)
.Display

' Remove HTML formatting from text updates so it displays correctly in Excel.
PreviousUpdates.Text = Replace(PreviousUpdates, "<br>", vbCrLf)
LatestUpdate.Text = Replace(LatestUpdate, "<li>", "-")
LatestUpdate.Text = Replace(LatestUpdate, "<br>", vbCrLf)
```

So what this code is doing is replacing the Excel carriage returns (vbCrLf) with HTML line breaks (< br >). It is also looking for a dash, and replacing that with the bullet list HTML tag.

Once populated in the email, it's then removing the HTML formatting so that the text is displayed correctly in Excel.

It's not perfect, but it works and it's simple for people to use.